# Enable an excel com add in for one and only one workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel

We're using an add in for excel to get reports from a 3:d party application but it's very slow so preferably I'd want to only enable it for this particular workbook. Is it possible to enable the add in to only this workbook?

Comment: I was thinking write a macro that says on open, enable add on, then on close disable add on, this may get you so far towards that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810570/how-to-enable-add-and-disable-remove-an-excel-add-in-using-vba

Comment: I've done what @PeterH describes. The code to add the connection and run it can be "discovered" by recording a macro. The code to disable/delete is similar to: `ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(1).Delete` (I think I had to search for this).

Comment: @gns100 you should add as an answer, I would be interested to see what it looks like

Answer (score 0):

I've done what @PeterH describes in the comment to your question. Actually a little more, Here's my unaltered code except for connection string:

```
Sub getGrantInfo()
For Each makeSheet In Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("grantTable").ListRows
    Sheets.Add Before:=Worksheets(1)
    ActiveSheet.Name = makeSheet.Range.Cells(1, 1).Value
    'get data
    With Worksheets(makeSheet.Range.Cells(1, 1).Value).ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
        "OLEDB;Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Password="******";Persist Security Info=True;User ID=*****;Data Source=******;Extended Properties=""" _
        , """"), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = makeSheet.Range.Cells(1, 2).Value
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = makeSheet.Range.Cells(1, 1).Value
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(1).Delete
Next makeSheet 
End Sub
```

As for the explanation, this VBA:

1. loops through a table (the `For Each-Next` block) of sheet names and SQL for the data that will go on that sheet, see screenshot example, I can't recall if there is a real limit beyond number of sheets Excel can handle for this table.[image: ![enter image description here]
2. Adds a new sheet, and names it based on the name in the worksheet column from the table
3. The `With-End With` block is making the connection to the database (note password, UserID, and source I changed to asterisks), your connection will look different depending on the database provider. Hence my suggestion to record a macro to create the connection. But if I recall correctly, creates the whole `With-End With` block.
4. Note the `Destination:=` command tells where on the worksheet to start putting the data.
5. Note the`.CommandText` that variable is the SQL from the table.
6. Note the `.ListObject.DisplayName` that is naming the table that is being created on the new worksheet.
7. Deletes the connection that was just used. If I remember correctly, if you don't delete here it will keep adding new connections (iterate the number 1) and I think you'll have to create a new loop to delete them one at a time, I don't think you can delete them all at once.

**In summary**, I believe you just need the `With-End With` block modified to your connection and the `ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(1).Delete` command after that, with other modifications to do exactly what you are looking for (copying and pasting the data to a non macro file as an example).

I put the whole routine to give others possible ideas to automate pulling data from a datasource, or possibly more datasources with modification.