# Use Excel cell reference (Parameterize) in SQL Query to local SQL server

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I want to use 2 columns in excel (A & B) as parameters in an SQL query to an SQL Server.  I then want to drag the query down 200 lines to select the required data from the DB.

[Pic with Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdkV9.png)

**I have tried**

Get Data > From Microsoft Query - Didn't work.  It just doesn't seem to be the right avenue for this (ie: No option for this).

Get Data > From SQL Server Database and it brings up Navigator and I see a preview of the data.  I don't want to import all the data though.  I want to customize a query and only import that data.

This is not a duplicate of [How do I write a query in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and then use that Query in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/193258/how-do-i-write-a-query-in-microsoft-sql-server-management-studio-and-then-use-th?rq=1) since those steps don't work in Excel 2016.

Comment: Since you are trying to get data from Excel to SQL then U may use,, `SELECT Col, Col2
FROM   [sheet1$A1:D25]
WHERE  COLNAME in (SELECT * FROM  [sheet1$F1:F2])`,, here `A1:D15` works as database and `F1:F2` as Parameter cells. If U are thinking get Data from SQL the better use `Get Data from SQL` and follow the procedure and in design view you can write SQL statement !

Comment: This [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1530465/enable-an-excel-com-add-in-for-one-and-only-one-workbook) may work for you...